# Splashscreen and Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, splash-screen

I'm developing this android application, that receives data from the gallery (in my case an image) and displays it. What i also had to do is to create a `SplashScreen` for my app. But when i did my intent became null .

> Manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.xkbc1923.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AlertExampleActivity">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

> SplashScreen

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
private static final int DISPLAY_DURATION = 1000;
@Override
protected final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, AlertExampleActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, DISPLAY_DURATION);
}
}
```

> MainActivity

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import static android.provider.CalendarContract.CalendarCache.URI;
public class AlertExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView picView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ///get the image view
    //get the text view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert_example);

    picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
    TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    if (txtView ==null) {
        Log.w("Example", "TextView is null");
    }

    //get the received intent
    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
    //get the action
    String receivedAction = receivedIntent.getAction();
    //find out what we are dealing with
    String receivedType = receivedIntent.getType();
    //make sure it's an action and type we can handle
    if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
        Log.d("Example", "Send received");
        //content is being shared
        if (receivedType.startsWith("text/")) {
            Log.d("Example", "Text received");

            //handle sent text
            //hide the other ui item
            picView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //get the received text
            String receivedText = receivedIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            //check we have a string
            if (receivedText != null) {
                //set the text
               txtView.setText(receivedText);
            }
        } else if (receivedType.startsWith("image/")) {
            Log.d("Example", "Image received");
            //handle sent image
            handleSendImage(receivedIntent);
        }

    } else if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
        //app has been launched directly, not from share list
        Log.d("Example", "Direct launch of App");
    }
}

private void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    // Get the image URI from intent
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    // When image URI is not null
    if (imageUri != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect image being shared
        picView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured, URI is invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you write details? When your intent become null? In which Activity?

Comment: Here's the error i have : 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.xkbc1923.myapplication.AlertExampleActivity.onCreate(AlertExampleActivity.java:48)

Comment: You did not add any extra data to your intent. So it would be null normally. Just add necessary data to intent (i) on SplashScreen.java. Ex - i.putExtra("key", "value"); i.setAction("action"); i.setType("type");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add any extra data to your intent. So it would be null normally. Just add necessary data to `Intent` (i) on `SplashScreen.java`. Ex -

```
i.setAction("action"); 
i.setType("type");
i.putExtra("key", "value");
```

Comment: I tried this :   Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, AlertExampleActivity.class);

                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                i.setType("image/*");
                String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
                startActivity(i);

Comment: But the thing is , now i don't receive the image anymore.

Comment: Please share your modified code. May be ImageView is not visible for this - picView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: I've shared it down below

Comment: You used picView.setVisibility(View.GONE) on  AlertExampleActivity. May be this is your ImageView that you want to show your image. Make it picView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); . So it would be visible.

Comment: That's not it ...  i put the intent filter in the SplashscreenActivity so i can get the splashscreen even when the application is externally called. But then my MainActivity doesn't receive the image.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this gonna solve your problem but you can try.

Instead of :

```
Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, AlertExampleActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // close this activity
            finish();
```

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, AlertExampleActivity.class));
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the manifest file since i want the splashscreen to appear even when it's externally called .

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".AlertExampleActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>



    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

And changed the SplashscreenActivity :

```
 public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

private static final int DISPLAY_DURATION = 1000;

@Override
protected final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, AlertExampleActivity.class);

            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("*/*");
            String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, DISPLAY_DURATION);
}
}
```

I haven't changed anything in the MainActivity , but now i no longer receive the image ... I'm new to Android so i would really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Can you show me the image/object which you cant receive from MainActivity? Are you talking about this-                                           String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);

Comment: The thing is , since i set the Action to be an ACTION_SEND , even when i'm launching the app directly it's giving me a SEND while it should be a MAIN.